# Create group and time specific means in R

Tags: r, panel, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have a panel dataset in a long format. I'm trying to create an object with period- and group-specific means in order to create a specific plot.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
yes.perc <- c(66.7, 60.1, 50, 38.2, 55.3, 49)
ref.code <- c(6040,6041,6040,6041,6040,6041)
treat <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
year <- c(2010, 2012, 2010, 2012, 2010, 2012)
df <- as.data.frame(c(id, yes.perc, ref.code, treat, year)
```

One of the things I tried was this:

```
means.t <- c(mean(df$yes.perc [df$year==2010&df$treat==1]),
mean(df$yes.perc [df$year==2012&df$treat==1]))
means.c <- c(mean(df$yes.perc [df$year==2010&df$treat==0]),
mean(df$yes.perc [df$year==2012&df$treat==0]))
```

I also tried this:

```
df %>% group_by(year, treat)%>% summarise(year.mean=mean(yes.perc))
```

All I get is NAs and I don't get why

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: df %>% group_by(year)%>% summarise(mean=mean(yes.perc))

Comment: When creating your data frame: `df <- data.frame(id, yes.perc, ref.code, treat, year)`

Comment: It doesn't work either: it just gives a 1-row NA, and even if it did work I am trying to create year-specific means for the 2 values of "treat" so it wouldn't work, but thanks!

Comment: you could do `group_by(treat, year)`

Comment: I did and I get the same as with the method I showed in the question: All NAs

Comment: Perhaps some missings in your (real) data? Have you tried `mean(yes.perc, na.rm = TRUE)`? Also. At least in your example data there is only one value of `treat` per `year`, i.e. 1 for 2010, 0 for 2012. Hence only one mean per year when summarising.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
yes.perc <- c(66.7, 60.1, 50, 38.2, 55.3, 49)
ref.code <- c(6040,6041,6040,6041,6040,6041)
treat <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0)
year <- c(2010, 2012, 2010, 2012, 2010, 2012)
df <- data.frame(id, yes.perc, ref.code, treat, year)
df %>% group_by(year, treat)%>% summarise(year.mean=mean(yes.perc))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   year [2]
#>    year treat year.mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  2010     1      57.3
#> 2  2012     0      49.1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this solve your probelm?